# OpenGL ES: Undo in a Pixel Painting App

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, pixel, undo

I'm currently working on an app that allows the user to draw pixelated images using OpenGL ES, but I don't know how to implement an undo function.
How could I do it? I thought of using an image for every pixel and adding it to an array. Basically, how can I store the rectangles I use as pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try :

```
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:vertexBuffer length:vertexCount * sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * 2] ;
if (self.vertexBuffers == nil) self.vertexBuffers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.vertexBuffers addObject:data];

save every draw point to a array;

if undo
```

1. clear old `buffer`

   ```
   glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   ```
2. remove point from `array;`

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
   {
   [self.vertexBuffers removeLastObject];
   }
   ```
3. render

   ```
   for (NSData *point in self.vertexBuffers)
   {
       NSUInteger count = point.length / (sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * 2);
       glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, point.bytes);
       glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, count);
   }
   ```
4. display `buffer`

   ```
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
   ```

other solution:
 You can grab an image from OpenGL ES context everytime you draw something and save in application's bundle as image file. This saves application's run memory.
 When undo is pressed you just draw previous saved image into the context and that's it.

See [OpenGL ES Simple Undo Last Drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708055/opengl-es-simple-undo-last-drawing)

Comment: Undo normally removes the last action only.Why you call removeLastObject 50 times?

Comment: Has anyone made this work on OpenGL ES 2? I have it working on ES 1, but when I copy it over to ES 2 it doesn't work. Im pretty sure it has to do with the re-rendering of the buffers (#3 and $4 above). Can anyone offer any insight. When it re-renders it doesn't draw all the paint, but only a few points...

Answer (score 2):

```
how can I store the rectangles I use as pixels?
```

I'm not sure you've got the basic setup right. You should be using a big texture acting as the canvas. Any user painting operations should affect only this texture (which you will be updating with glTexSubImage2D). Then on every frame you should redraw this texture on the screen.

A simple N-steps undo system would consist on a circular list of N textures / canvases.